# Rails 4 and Heroku - rake assets:precompile trying to call Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

So I've spent a day on this and read every SO question even mildly related, and checked the Heroku docs.

This is an Heroku issue when pushing:

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   rake aborted!
   could not connect to server: Connection refused
   Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I'm sure it's familiar.

A lot of stuff changed with Heroku deployment on Rails 4 I am aware, but I even tried many of the pre 4.0 suggestions to try and fix it.

Its:

```
   /tmp/build_22xpuyyrmltz6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:825:in `initialize'
   /tmp/build_22xpuyyrmltz6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:825:in `new'
   /tmp/build_22xpuyyrmltz6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:825:in `connect'
   /tmp/build_22xpuyyrmltz6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:542:in `initialize'
   /tmp/build_22xpuyyrmltz6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
   /tmp/build_22xpuyyrmltz6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
```

etc... so from what I gather this is because is trying to access the db during compile time.

My question so far is a carbon copy of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432825/heroku-precompile-assets-failed-on-rail-4-app)

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Runs fine and the manifest.json is generated, yet Heroku doesn't recognise it.

I also tried this, but I think Rails 4 is false by default anyway.

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

So then a workaround-ish thing I was happy to try was:

```
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile
```

and I tried this the most, created new heroku apps, toggled it on and off and on again. Tried multiple pushes. I was committing when needed as well so it wasn't that.

also tried rails_12factor and some other stuff I can't remember. All to no avail.

Is there something I'm missing? user-env-compile seems to be solving everybody else's problems but seemingly has no effect for me.

I've even restarted my computer a few times... any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you probably have some gem that is trying to access the database during asset-compilation. do you have a `mount` statement in your routes file?

Comment: Yeah, mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'

and I thought that was what is happening, in the end I just ditched heroku. A little too hands-off for these situations I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a gem somewhere that is trying to connect to the database. In my case it was acts_as_taggable_on. I [filed a bug with the maintainer](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/issues/396). If I commented out the lines in my model that were using it, precompilation worked fine:

```
# acts_as_taggable
# accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags
```

If sidekiq is your offender, you can work around this by commenting out the mount statement, precompiling the assets locally, and pushing them to heroku. If the maintainer of the gem fixes the bug, you can then go back to precompiling during slug compilation.

Kind of cumbersome, because you have to remember to revert the routes file (i.e. not accidentally commit with the commented-out mount statement).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar issue, when the 'Postgres Add-on' was not enabled for my app in Heroku.