# Heroku Rails 4 static assets not showing

Tags: heroku, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4

I updated my app to Rails 4 but it failed deploying to Heroku when running asset precompile. As other questions have touched on, I think this was failing due to attempting to find an `ENV` variable that didn't exist for my redis-to-go. So I added the Heroku labs feature mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432825/heroku-precompile-assets-failed-on-rail-4-app). I also followed Heroku's suggestions in [this post](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails4).

That fixed the error during precompile but my assets aren't showing. Things I've done:

- Added the `rails_12factor` gem
- Tried running `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:compile` locally (after commenting out the redis `ENV["redistogo_url"]` bit
- Added `config.serve_static_assets = true` to my `production.rb` file

Yet none of this seems to work. It could be that I didn't do this in the proper order. I know from other questions others have found success so am wondering what else I can try.

Comment: Hi Travis! Did you get this working?

Comment: Hola @AndyAtkinson! I didn't, unfortunately. I'm going to go back and give it another go soon. I have another app running Rails 4 with assets, but it's a bit spotty. I must be doing something crazy.

Comment: Ok, so after a crap ton of changes (including upgrading to Rails 4.1.5) I finally think this works. I was able to get by `rake assets:precompile` but the assets didn't show. It seems that in the update process I never set `config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header` to `nil` instead of `"X-Sendfile"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came back to this after a while, and got it working. A few things since the last attempt:

- I didn't need to precompile assets locally
- I had to set `config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header` to `nil` in `production.rb`
- Bundled and ran `sprockets_better_errors` gem locally, and added its recommendations in `application.css.scss` (even though I don't think I really needed to?)

That's about all.